# Where can I download an older version of Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, links

I'm looking for specific versions of Google Chrome but I cannot find them. I don't want a random site that offers me to download these. It must be safe, preferably of Google itself.

I could find one for Firefox: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

I imagine there must be something like that offered by Google for Google Chrome?

Comment: If it's about a short test of a website in an older browser, you can also emulate one very easily on browserstack.com. you don't need to download anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705280/how-to-download-an-old-version-of-chrome

Here is the same question from stackoverflow. Different stack exchange, so you might have probably missed it.

Anyway, there is no official way to download. But there are some decent sites providing old versions. One such site is linked in the answer to that stack overflow question.

Here is one more link. 
[Dead link]
Kindly note that I have not tested this link personally. Although an initial test says the download is free of malware. I will still exercise caution while installing.

Comment: This linked answer has since been deleted.  :(

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will remove the links.